# How to trim a picture with rmarkdown/html?

Tags: html, r, image, r-markdown

I want to include a picture form the web in my markdown document, but I just want the left part of the picture. I searched on how to trim picture with rmarkdown but I found nothing...

Here is an example

````
---
title: "How to trim?"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = 'center')
```

Include picture

```{r pic}
include_graphics("http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/README-example-1.png")
```
````

which gave me this HTML output.

[image]

If I want to trim the legend (the ~20% right part), how can I do?

I accept any type of answer: relative or absolute specifiation, rmarkdown or html solution, ...

Thanks!

Comment: look at the `magick` package.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr ! I published an answer using this package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
library(magick)
crop <- function(im, left = 0, top = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0) {
  d <- dim(im[[1]]); w <- d[2]; h <- d[3]
  image_crop(im, glue::glue("{w-left-right}x{h-top-bottom}+{left}+{top}"))
}
"http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/README-example-1.png" %>%
  image_read() %>%
  crop(right = 210)
```

Comment: rly nice use of `glue()` to make the stringified params to `magick` very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) comment, I found a solution.

```
library(magick)
library(magrittr)
image_read("http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/README-example-1.png") %>% 
  image_flop() %>% 
  image_crop("1344x960+250") %>% 
  image_flop()
```

I'm not sure it's the most efficient with the two `image_flop()` functions and I don't understand precisly the `"1344x960+250"` but it works :)